# How to fix error with "class" when creating a dhcp split-scope on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp

I'm trying to split a dhcp scope between a existing domain controller TTP01 and the new DC TTP02 to provide failover.

I'm using the the wizard in DHCP > [my scope] > Advanced > Split-scope.

In the final step I get an error saying:

```
Migration of Scope Options on Added DHCP Server: Failed    
Error: 0x00004E4C - The class name being used is unknown or incorrect.
```

I can't find anything that seems to be wrong with my Scope Options settings, they are:

```
Option Name           Vendor    Value          Class
003 Router            Standard  192.168.137.1  None
006 DNS Server        Standard  192.168.137.2  None
015 DNS Domain Name   Standard  ttp.local      None
060 PXEClient         Standard  PXEClient      None
```

I can't find any information about this error except this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc448726%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) when searching. How do make it work?

Comment: What happens if you add these scope options manually on the second server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use the split-scope wizard (which is a relatively new feature) in order to split your DHCP scope.

All you need to do is:

1. Configure the same DHCP pool and scope options on both servers.
2. Exclude opposite halves of the pool on each of the two servers.
3. Set a delay on one server so that you don't get two responses to the same request

One example of how you could configure a split scope manually:

- Network: 192.168.0.0/24
- Server A Configuration:

  - DHCP Pool: 192.168.0.128 through 192.168.0.254
  - Exclusion: 192.168.0.192 through 192.168.0.254
- Server B Configuration:

  - DHCP Pool: 192.168.0.128 through 192.168.0.254
  - Exclusion: 192.168.0.128 through 192.168.0.191
  - Delay: 1000ms

That's really all there is to it. Be sure to make your DHCP pool at least twice as big as the number of devices that you expect. More info is available in [Weestro's blog entry on the Split-Scope Wizard](http://weestro.blogspot.com/2010/09/split-scope-dhcp-in-server-2008-r2.html), which also demonstrates exactly what it does.